# Is there a combinatorial interpretation of the arithmetic derivative?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, derivations

The arithmetic derivative is a derivation on $\mathbb{Z}$ that is $1$ for all prime numbers.  On positive integers other than 1, this always returns a positive integer.  My question is, is there a way to interpret the arithmetic derivative as counting something?

Comment: OEIS says that: "Let n be the product of a multiset P of k primes. Consider the k-dimensional box whose edges are the elements of P. Then the (k-1)-dimensional surface of this box is 2a(n). For example, 2a(25) = 20, the perimeter of a 5 X 5 square. Similarly, 2a(18) = 42, the surface area of a 2 X 3 X 3 box. - David W. Wilson, Mar 11 2011"

Comment: https://oeis.org/A003415